# Reading performance counters for Intel Xeon in userspace

Tags: linux, x86, intel-pmu

I want to read performance counters for intel xeon using a shell script in userspace. Oprofile will not work as it is too rigid to fulfill my requirements. I am using FC13. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perf will allow you to select which counters you want and also has the ability to output in machine readable form. https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page